# nl - numbering input in descending order

Tags: files, numbering, nl

Is this possible to number file lines in descending order?

That would be something like:

```
nl -i -1
```

unfortunately this gives me:

```
nl: invalid line number increment: ‘-1’: Numerical result out of range
```

I know that it has no sense in pipe redirection, as `nl` can't guess number of total lines, but if I pass file as an argument it should be quite easy - even it it needs two passes to accomplish the task.

If not `nl` than maybe some other command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reversing the lines, numbering them and reversing again:

```
tac | nl | tac
```